# EF Core global filter query by userId

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have situation where I would like to filter tables by logged-in userId or to be exact some field called `AllowedVehicles`.
Thing is that `identityContext` has populated field `AllowedVehicles` only when it is logged-in and after is `AllowedVehicles` property actually read from database. My code doesn't work since `AllowedVehicles` is empty list once `OnModelCreating` is executed and it is **executed only once**.

How can I make global filter query in this case.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyGlobalFilters<IBaseEntity>(x => x.DeletedAt == null);
    if (_identityContext != null && _identityContext.AllowedVehicles.Count() > 0)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyGlobalFilters<Vehicle>(x => _identityContext.AllowedVehicles.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(x.Id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnModelCreating` is called only once per DbContext class. And you do not have to expect that you may apply filter conditionally.

One solution is to define your conditions in filter:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyGlobalFilters<IBaseEntity>(x => x.DeletedAt == null);

    modelBuilder.ApplyGlobalFilters<Vehicle>(x => _identityContext == null 
        || !_identityContext.AllowedVehicles.Any() 
        || _identityContext.AllowedVehicles.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(x.Id)
    );
}
```